# Decimal and only positive numeric values

Tags: c#, regex

What regex i can use for positive numeric and decimal values ?

```
Accepted values: 0, 22.5 , 0.35 , 89 , .38
Invalid values : -22 , -.25 , -0.66 , abc, -22abc, 55er
```

I have tried this but i get error

```
^\d*\.?\d*[1-9]+\d*$)|(^[1-9]+\d*\.\d*$"
```

> Too many )'s

```
^\d*\.?\d*[1-9]+\d*$)|(^[1-9]+\d*\.\d*$
```

Comment: Where do you want to use this?  As noted in @stimms answer, using `decimal.TryParse` and a simple comparison would be more bullet proof

Comment: I will be using this on text box event txtbox_PreviewTextInput in wpf. I have method in place which validates input and if it is not valid then it discards user input.

Comment: Then just combine `decimal.TryParse` cascading to a comparison with `0m` (it's not clear from your question whether 0 is a valid "positive" value).  It's a lot simpler and easier to read.

Comment: zero is the valid value.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a closing `)` in the regex.

```
^\d*\.?\d*[1-9]+\d*$)|(^[1-9]+\d*\.\d*)$
```

However, I'd strongly suggest you look at `Decimal.TryParse` instead of trying to validate numbers using the format of a string yourself.

Comment: Was just about to comment that last paragraph. Easier to read (and thus maintain) too IMO. +1 for the suggestion of a better option.

Comment: This regex is still missing an opening parenthesis making it invalid regex. As I can see, parenthesis are not even needed for this regex. Also this regex is unnecessarily complex and can be simplified.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply your pattern to this:

```
\d*(?:\.\d+)?
```

### Demo

This seems to cover all your positive decimal number use cases.  The decimal component is optional, meaning that the pattern covers integers.  Decimal numbers are covered, and also numbers which only have a decimal component.

Note that you might have to surround the pattern with `^$` anchors, depending on the particular API you are using.

**Edit:**

If you also need to ensure that empty string is not matched, then we can add a lookahead to the above pattern:

```
(?=.)\d*(?:\.\d+)?
```

### Demo

Comment: Little problem in this regex as it will match empty string too.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Thanks for pointing this out.  I have added a fix for the problem you identified.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you want to stay away from Regex, one of these might work:

```
 private static bool IsPositiveDecimal(string decimalString)
 {
     return decimal.TryParse(decimalString, out var aDecimal) && aDecimal >= 0;
 }
```

or

```
 private static bool TryParsePositiveDecimal(string decimalString, out decimal aDecimal)
 {
     return decimal.TryParse(decimalString, out aDecimal) && aDecimal >= 0;
 }
```

If you feed the latter one a non-positive decimal, it will return false, but will return the parsed decimal in the out parameter.

This should suit your needs without injecting a complicated Regex into your code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this regex should meet all the cases and will only match valid samples and discard all invalid ones.

```
^(?:[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?|0?\.\d+|0)$
```

**Regex Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?:` - Start of non capture group
- `[1-9]\d*` - Matches a number without unneeded preceding zeroes. Will invalidated `01` or `001`
- `(\.\d+)?` - Can optionally have decimal part
- `|` - Alternation
- `0?\.\d+` - Allows only decimal numbers that can optionally have zero before them. E.g. to support numbers like `0.11` or `.11`
- `|` - Alternation
- `0` - Supporting literal zero as a special case
- `)` - closing of non-capture group
- `$` - End of string

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hqC6vK/1)**

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d*\.?\d+$
```

There will also match 0.00 .00 0.0